# Why is a mechanical advantage less than 1 required for class 3 levers?

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics, torque, rotational-kinematics

From what I understand, mechanical advantage is equal to the ratio of force produced to force applied, which is equal to the ratio of effort to load and effort arm length to load arm length
[image: mechanical advantage]

[image: mechanical advantage]

Therefore, I would assume that if the ratio of force produced to force applied is less than one that means more effort is required for less results. But third class levers are designed like this. Why would a mechanical advantage less than 1 be advantageous?

https://letstalkscience.ca/educational-resources/backgrounders/simple-machines-levers

https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/machine-has-mechanical-advantage-less-than-one-725103